# Frame work or Vanilla? how to add content to the page without loading separate html pages?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, frontend

(firstly thanks for the help and time looking at this) -

OK so there are allot of frame works out there and i've been going round in circles trying to find the right language to do what I need -

I'm looking to create a web page (personal site) - which is only one page but when clicking on links (such as blog and projects) it then removes the main content on the page and re-populates it with the blog main content ect -

Ideally there would be some type of animation transition between pages -

From looking at some portfolio sites a good example of what I am trying to create is https://jasonliao.co.nz/

Any help here would be great -

Ideally to know:

what is this method called (loading pages without refreshing the page) 
Can this be done using vanilla JS? (i'd love to get amazing as one language before throwing in frameworks on top of it) -

Yes I am kinda new to this side of development so any help is really appreciated - thanks, 
Wally

Answer (score 0):

I recommend start by learning basic JS (Java Script) then once your confident then move onto JQuery. Udemy would have a few basic courses.

What your asking is really broad as many languages and frameworks could do it. Its more what your use to or features your site will require. eg do you require back-end functions if so then you will need to use something like PHP or Node

Comment: Hi Tony - Thanks for your help here. I've got the basics of JS down - The site I have built works off one page currently but this is because I am using css animations and JS createElemets combined with append child to add and remove content. Maybe I should have asked is there a way to appendChild a html page to a current div section of the document - for instance swapping out the main content wrapper for another. Thanks again ;) really appreciate the help - wally

Comment: If you already have JS and Jquery down packed then have a look at Angular JS. 

As for swapping out content I generally create a .hidden class (css display: none;) then use JQuery onclick function to add on remove that hidden class. But it really depends what your trying to achieve as that method is more for basic content swapping.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for the help Tony :)

Answer (score 0):

This guy was probably using Angular or React for this. It is single page application (SPA). Whole app is loaded in the browser and if it needs some data, it will send HTTP requests to the servers and get data as JSON. If you want to make similar things with vanilla JS, you must use Ajax and do alot of DOM manipulation to achieve the same thing :)